# Función javascript no funciona con la etiqueta form

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buen día. Tengo un problema al ejecutar este código cuando cambio la etiqueta **DIV** por un **FORM**. Tengo dos cajas una está oculta detrás de la otra, al iniciar la página se muestra por unos segundos la segunda caja y posteriormente se oculta. Al hacer clic en el botón **ABRIR** se abre la caja y permanece abierta hasta que se haga clic en el botón **CERRAR**. Todo bien funciona al **EJECUTAR** lo siguiente:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  openInfo();
  setTimeout(closeInfo, 1000);
});

function openInfo() {
  document.querySelector('.b-form').style.opacity = '0.01';
  document.querySelector('.box-form').style.left = '-37%';
  document.querySelector('.box-info').style.right = '-37%';
}

function closeInfo() {
  document.querySelector('.b-form').style.opacity = '1';
  document.querySelector('.box-form').style.left = '0px';
  document.querySelector('.box-info').style.right = '-5px';
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.i {
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
}
.i-more,
.i-left {
  color: cadetblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box {
  width: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box-form {
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box-demo {
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  height: 9rem;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box-info {
  width: 260px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 7rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  z-index: 0;
}
.b {
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.b-form {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  float: right;
}
.b-info {
  float: left;
}
.fieldset-body {
  display: table;
}
.box-form,
.box-info,
.b {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-form">
      <div class="box-demo">
        <div class="fieldset-body" id="demo">
          <button onclick="openInfo();" class="b b-form i i-more">ABRIR</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-info">
      <p><button onclick="closeInfo();" class="b b-info i i-left">CERRAR</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

El problema es que necesito en esta parte del código:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Usar la etiqueta form quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
<form class="box"></form>
```

Pero al hacer eso el código javascript no funciona correctamente, cuando hago clic en el botón **ABRIR** se cierra automáticamente cuando debería permanecer abierta la segunda caja, hasta hacer clic en **CERRAR**. El comportamiento es como si fuera la primera vez que carga la página.

Tengo la demo en: [DemoStackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-rtdytn?file=index.html) reproduciendo el problema aquí está cambiado la etiqueta **DIV** por **FORM**.

Comment: Es un error muy común, debes añadir a tus 2 botones el atributo `type="button"`, de lo contrario su comportamiento por defecto será de `submit`, lo que hace que la página se recargue ya que se envía el formulario. Puedes verlo en el mismo [`stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-gkvy5j?file=index.html) funcionando, sólo he agregado el atributo `type="button"` en ambos botones. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El elemento [`button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tiene la propiedad [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) que por defecto es `submit` (*si... suena raro, pero es así*)

Al hacer `clic` sobre un botón tipo `submit` provoca que el formulario que lo contiene se envíe.

Esto hace que la página se recargue. En tu caso, la recarga se hace tan rápido que pareciera que se ejecuta el cerrar, pero no es eso.

#### Solución:

Definir los botones como `type="button"`

**Ejemplo:**

```js
function openInfo() {
  document.querySelector('.b-form').style.opacity = '0.01';
  document.querySelector('.box-form').style.left = '-37%';
  document.querySelector('.box-info').style.right = '-37%';
}

function closeInfo() {
  document.querySelector('.b-form').style.opacity = '1';
  document.querySelector('.box-form').style.left = '0px';
  document.querySelector('.box-info').style.right = '-5px';
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.i {
  width: 70px;
  height: 20px;
}
.i-more,
.i-left {
  color: cadetblue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.box {
  width: 330px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box-form {
  width: 320px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box-demo {
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  height: 9rem;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.box-info {
  width: 260px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 7rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: chartreuse;
  z-index: 0;
}
.b {
  height: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.b-form {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  float: right;
}
.b-info {
  float: left;
}
.fieldset-body {
  display: table;
}
.box-form,
.box-info,
.b {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form class="box">
    <div class="box-form">
      <div class="box-demo">
        <div class="fieldset-body" id="demo">
          <button type="button" onclick="openInfo();" class="b b-form i i-more">ABRIR</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-info">
      <p><button type="button" onclick="closeInfo();" class="b b-info i i-left">CERRAR</button></p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: De igual forma puedes cancelar este comportamiento con el método preventDefault()